# Dapper.net, Specified cast is not valid. cannot use type float

Tags: sql-server-2008, dapper

I have a table,there's a field called "water", the data type for this field in `sql server 2008` is float.

in my code, I also use `float`.

```
 public float? Water { get; set; }
```

here's the error message I got.

```
{"Specified cast is not valid."}
{"Error parsing column 2 (Water=15.87 - Double)"}
```

if I changed the type to double , everything works.

```
 public double? Water { get; set; }
```

I went back to the Database, all values for water field are between 0-100. there are a few nulls.

please explain to me why I have to use double instead of float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Dapper`. If you check the `SqlDbType` conversion site, you'll notice that a `float` in SQL Server is a `double` in `.NET`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText